# lightswitch conflict with proxies and client lsml

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

All of a sudden I get an error with my client and proxies lsml saying there are conflicts with the id with another model in file Proxies.lsml. I have tried getting a previous version but wont work :(

Comment: Save yourself a lot of heartache and checkout the previous working version.

Comment: ok I got passed that now i got one error saying model failed to load another extension with the same name exists 'lightswitch'

Comment: It's brutal, you've gotta be an lsml ninja.  Did it break after a git/svn merge?

Comment: Nope it broke after I fixed the lsml file issues by getting previous ones from tfs

Comment: does not even point to a file